# Timeout while getting a connection from pool

Tags: c#, postgresql

Está dando esse erro. Estou usando postgres

```
Erro ao buscar servidor por id: Timeout while getting a connection from pool.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in BackupDAO.dll
```

Metodo

```
public Servidor buscarPorID(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            DAOFactoryNuvem dao = new DAOFactoryNuvem();
            conexao = dao.CriaConexao();

            String sql = "select * from servidor where id = "+id;
            NpgsqlCommand sqlCon = new NpgsqlCommand(@sql, conexao);
            conexao.Open();

            NpgsqlDataReader drCon;

            drCon = sqlCon.ExecuteReader();

            while (drCon.Read())
            {
                Servidor servidor = new Servidor(Convert.ToInt32(drCon[0]), drCon[1].ToString(), drCon[2].ToString());
                drCon.Close();

                return servidor;
            }

            Servidor servidor1 = new Servidor(0, "", "");

            conexao.Dispose();
            return servidor1;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro ao buscar servidor por id: " + erro.Message);
            throw erro;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.Clone();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá,

Adicione na sua string de conexão e veja se funcionou.

```
Pooling=false;
```

Eu chutaria que há muitas conexões abertas, mas olhei que voce da um dispose(); então não deve ser isso.

Comment: Mas tem muitos mais metodos em outras DAOs que são chamados ao mesmo tempo, mandei só esse pra não mandar todos, porque achei que o dispose podia estar no lugar errado. Vou tentar isso ai.

Comment: Tenta dar um dispose() em cada um. EU recomendaria utilizar apenas 1 Connection() e fechar ele. Melhor que abrir e fechar 1000 vezes.Se possível poste o resto do código, as outras DAOs

Comment: Uma conection por DAO no caso?